# Update record using EF

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

How can I perform an update using EF where the values I want to change are a relative.

Currently I do this

```
public Result UpdateResult(long resultID, int count)
{
    var result = this.UOW.GetRepository<Result>().GetAll().FirstOrDefault(sr => sr.ResultID == resultID);

    scheduleResult.count += count;

    return result;
}
```

But the problem is, in a distributed environment this could happen twice, and values could be missed as we essentially do a GET then an UPDATE.  How can I just perform an UPDATE as a single operation sending the `+=` to SQL server to ensure that SQL takes care of locking the row?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an stored procedure and run it. Or tun a SQL query directly on the server.

The DbContext.Database exposes functionality for this.

You can also use a [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818746(v=vs.110).aspx) ([MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx)) to keep both operations inside a transactions, but that's more expensive.